# geom_to_wkt() used in SQL results in zero length strings

Tags: qgis, sql

Using QGIS 3.22.11.

I have a project with a layer tree_pt. tree_pt contains 17 point features. I wish to obtain the geometry for each feature in WKT format using SQL. (I have similar layers containing line and polygon features, which I will treat similarly once I have got this working).

Using DB Manager, the following SQL results in what appears to be zero-length strings for each of the 17 features.

```
SELECT
    geom_to_wkt(geometry)
FROM tree_pt
```

[image: Screenshot of SQL and query output]

I would expect the output to contain 17 rows, each containing the geometry in WKT format, e.g. Point (564.13737133 214.32729203), or similar.

Is there something wrong in my SQL or approach, or is this a bug?

Comment: what sort of database is it? I'd usually use `st_aswkt` but I'm a postgis user

Comment: They're SHP files accessed via a QGIS project, so no inbuilt SQL engine. SQL will be provided via QGIS

Comment: try out st_astext(geometry) instead geom_to_wkt

Comment: why not use an expression instead then

Comment: @ Ian Turton - what expression would I use?

Comment: @ Marco - this works. Add it as an answer and I'll mark it as acceprted solution. Thanks

Comment: It seems that not all QGIS functions from the expression engine work in the SQL engine. The DB Manager doesn't complain, it just doesn't generate a column for them. `select geom_from_wkt('POINT(0 1)') from tree_pt` returns empty, `select nonsuch('POINT(0 1)') from tree_pt` returns "no such function".

Answer (score 7):

Try out `st_astext(geometry)` instead `geom_to_wkt`.